# how to solve an affine differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a general way to solve $y'=Ay+b$, with $y, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A$ a matrix, and where $A$ and $b$ are constant? I'm tempted to make the substitution $z = y+A^{-1}b$, and then use the matrix exponential, but what if $A$ is not invertible?

Comment: Use the integrating factor $e^{-At}$. The system is equivalent to $(e^{-At}y(t))'=e^{-At}b$.

Comment: @A.G. +1 for the suggestion. Still I prefer to use variation of constants method :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution of the following linear system

$$\dot{x(t)}=Ax(t)+Bu(t);x(t_0)=x_0$$

is given by

$$x(t)=e^{A(t-t_0)}x_0+\int_{t_0}^t \! e^{A(t-\tau)}Bu(\tau) \, \mathrm{d}\tau.$$

This can be proved via Laplace transform method. For your system the input $u(.)\in\mathbb{R}$ can be represented by the step function.